# Backup of home folder store network and printer settings?

Tags: backup, elementary-os

Does restoring my home folder, restore network and printer settings on elementary os?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't. Those are handled by the system and will be in system config files
`/etc/NetworkManager` is the directory where network settings are stored.
As for printer settings - the man pages says "`The printers.conf file defines the local printers that are available. It is normally located in the /etc/cups directory and is generated automatically by the cupsd(8) program when printers are added or deleted.`"